# Undefined index: page, Undefined variable: theme_name

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't customise page. I'm debugging now a Wordpress site because I have problems.

Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\wordpress-4.9.5-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\page\functions.php on line 72

Notice: Undefined variable: theme_name in D:\wordpress-4.9.5-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\page\functions.php on line 72

Where is the problem? What can I do?

```
   <?php global $theme_name, $theme_options, $color, $color_header, $pageid;
$theme_name = 'therestaurant';
$theme_options = get_option($theme_name);

// Translation
load_theme_textdomain($theme_name);

// Get theme colors from settings
if (!is_admin()) {
    include_once("csscolor.php");
    $color = new CSS_Color($theme_options['cp_color']);
    $color_header = new CSS_Color($theme_options['cp_color_header']);
}

//include the admin controlpanel
if (is_admin()) {
    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/backend/controlpanel.php');
    $cpanel = new ControlPanel();
    require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/backend/customfields.php');
}

//load frontend scripts
function script_loader() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        global $theme_options;
        wp_register_style('font2', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=OFL+Sorts+Mill+Goudy+TT:regular,italic');
        wp_enqueue_style('font2');

        wp_register_style('style', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'));
        wp_enqueue_style('style');

        wp_register_style('responsive_style', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/responsive.css', array('style'));
        wp_enqueue_style('responsive_style');

        /*wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');*/
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        if ($theme_options['cp_slider_show'] != 'disabled') {
            wp_register_script('nivo', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js', array("jquery"));
            wp_enqueue_script('nivo');
            wp_register_style('nivostyle', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/nivo-slider.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('nivostyle');
        }

        wp_register_script('cufon', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/fonts/cufon-yui.js', array("jquery"));
        wp_enqueue_script('cufon');
        wp_register_script('font', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/fonts/Junction_400.font.js', array("jquery"));
        wp_enqueue_script('font');

        wp_register_script('imgCenter', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.imgCenter.minified.js', array("jquery"));
        wp_enqueue_script('imgCenter');

        wp_register_script('fancybox', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array("jquery"));
        wp_enqueue_script('fancybox');
        wp_register_style('fancyboxstyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('fancyboxstyle');

        wp_register_style('cart66-css-custom', get_template_directory_uri().'/cart66.custom.css', array("cart66-css"));
        wp_enqueue_style('cart66-css-custom');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_loader');

//load backend scripts
function admin_script_loader() {
    wp_register_style('controlpanel', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/controlpanel.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('controlpanel');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');

    if ($_POST['page'] == $theme_name) {
        wp_register_style('mycolorpicker_style', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/css/colorpicker.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('mycolorpicker_style');
        wp_register_script('mycolorpicker', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/js/colorpicker.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('mycolorpicker');
        wp_register_script('mycolorpicker_eye', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/js/eye.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('mycolorpicker_eye');
        wp_register_script('mycolorpicker_utils', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/js/utils.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('mycolorpicker_utils');
        wp_register_script('mycolorpicker_layout', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2');
        wp_enqueue_script('mycolorpicker_layout');
    }

    wp_register_script('upload', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/upload.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
    wp_register_script('sortable', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/backend/sortable.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('sortable');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_script_loader');

//register the main wp3 menu
if (function_exists('register_nav_menu')) {
    //register_nav_menu('mainmenu', 'Main navigation menu');
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'mainmenu' => 'Main navigation menu',
            'mobilemenu' => 'Mobile navigation menu'
        )
    );
}

//custom media image sizes
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'menucard_thumb', 9999, 100 );
    add_image_size( 'gallery_thumb', 260, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'mediumwidth', 588, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'fullwidth', 906, 9999 );
    add_image_size( 'slider', 1020, 9999 );
}

// Custom post type for slider
function custom_post_type_slider() {
  global $theme_name;
  $labels = array(
    'name' => __('Slides', $theme_name ),
    'singular_name' => __('Slides', $theme_name ),
    'add_new' => __('Add New', $theme_name ),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Slide', $theme_name ),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Slide', $theme_name ),
    'new_item' => __('New Slide', $theme_name ),
    'view_item' => __('View Slide', $theme_name ),
    'search_items' => __('Search Slides', $theme_name ),
    'not_found' =>  __('No slides found', $theme_name ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No slides found in Trash', $theme_name ), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Slides', $theme_name )

  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => false, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','custom-fields')
  ); 
  register_post_type('slide',$args);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type_slider');

//register the sidebars
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Frontpage top (max 3)',
        'id' => 'frontpage',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="ribbon-container"><div class="title-container"><div class="title"><div class="bar-left"></div><div class="bar-right"></div><h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3></div></div></div>'
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Frontpage bottom',
        'id' => 'frontpage2',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer',
        'id' => 'footer-widgets',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
    if ($theme_options['cp_sidebar_name[]']) {
        foreach ($theme_options['cp_sidebar_name[]'] as $i=>$value) {
            if ($value) {
                $title = $theme_options['cp_sidebar_name[]'][$i];
                register_sidebar(array(
                    'name' => $title,
                    'id' => $title,
                    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidepanel">',
                    'after_widget' => '</div>',
                    'before_title' => '<h3>',
                    'after_title' => '</h3>'
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}

//load sidebar
function sidebar_pos() {
    global $post, $theme_options;
    $pageid = $post->ID;
    $sidebarpos = strtolower(get_post_meta($pageid, "sidebarpos", true));
    if ($sidebarpos == 'left' || $sidebarpos == 'right' || $sidebarpos == 'hidden') {
        $theme_options['cp_sidebar_position'] = $sidebarpos;
    }
    if ($theme_options['cp_sidebar_position'] == 'hidden') { 
        $pos = "fullwidthpage"; 
    } 
    elseif ($theme_options['cp_sidebar_position'] == 'left') {
        $pos = "sidebar_left";
    } 
    else { 
        $pos = "sidebar_right"; 
    }
    return $pos;
}

//create the breadcrumb
function the_breadcrumb() {
    global $theme_name;
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo '<div id="breadcrumbs">';
        echo '<a href="'.get_bloginfo("url").'">' . __( 'Home', $theme_name ) . '</a>';
        if (is_category() || is_single()) {
            $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
            if ($cat_ID) {
                echo ' / '.get_cat_name($cat_ID);
            } else {
                $categories = array_reverse(get_the_category());
                foreach($categories as $category) {
                    echo ' / <a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'">'.__($category->cat_name).'</a>';
                }   
            }
            if (is_single()) {
                echo ' / ';
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo ' / ';
            echo the_title();
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

//get custom page template path
function page_template($id = '') {
    if ($id) {
        $template = get_post_meta($id, "_wp_page_template", true);
    } else {
        global $wp_query;
        $template = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, "_wp_page_template", true);
    }
    return $template;
}

//get nice pagination
function nicepagination() {
    global $paged, $wp_query, $theme_name;

    // get the number of pages
    if ( !isset($max_page) ) {  
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    }

    // if there's more then 1 page..
    if( $max_page > 1 ){
        if ( !$paged ) $paged = 1;

        echo '<div class="centering"><ul class="paging">';

        if ( $paged > 1 ) {
            echo '<li class="previous readmore"><a href="' . get_pagenum_link($paged-1) . '">' . __( 'Previous', $theme_name ) . '</a></li>';
        }

        for ( $i=1; $i <= $max_page; $i++ ) {
            if ($i==1 || $i==$max_page || ($i>($paged-3) && $i<($paged+3))) {
                if ($i==$max_page && $i != $paged) echo '...';
                echo '<li class="readmore';
                if ( $i == $paged ) echo ' active';
                echo '">';
                echo '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link($i) . '">';
                echo $i;
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
                if ($i==1 && $i != $paged) echo '...';
            }
        }

        if ( $paged < $max_page ) {
            echo '<li class="next readmore"><a href="' . get_pagenum_link($paged+1) . '">' . __( 'Next', $theme_name ) . '</a></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}

// Enable shortcodes in widgets and wrap widget content in div
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

// Force wordpress to use full image quality (no compression)
function jpeg_full_quality( $quality ) { 
    return 100;
}
//if ($theme_options['cp_img_quality']) {
    add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_full_quality' );
//}

// Get stars
function get_stars() {
    global $theme_options;
    $numberStars = $theme_options['cp_stars'];
    if ($theme_options['cp_stars'] > 0) {
        for ($x=0; $x<$numberStars; $x++) {
            echo '<div class="star"></div>';
        }
    }
}

// Redirect to a gallery/blog/menucard category template
function custom_category_template($cat_template) {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb, $pageid;
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, pm.meta_value AS page_template, pm2.meta_value AS mc_categories FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " AS p ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM " . $wpdb->postmeta . " WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template') ";
    $sql .= "AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id ";
    $sql .= "LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM " . $wpdb->postmeta . " WHERE meta_key = 'categories') ";
    $sql .= "AS pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id ";
    $sql .= "WHERE pm.meta_value = 'gallery.php' OR pm.meta_value = 'blog.php' OR pm.meta_value = 'menucard.php' ";
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT);

    $catID = get_query_var('cat');
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $categories = explode(',', $row->mc_categories);
        if (in_array($catID, $categories)) {
            $path = TEMPLATEPATH . "/" . $row->page_template;
            if ( file_exists($path) ) {
                $cat_template = $path;
                $pageid = $row->ID;
            }

        }
    }

    return $cat_template;
}
add_filter('category_template', 'custom_category_template');

// Shortcodes
include_once('shortcodes.php');

// Custom widgets
include_once('widgets/rf_maps_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_featured_content_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_twitter_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_contact_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_latest_posts_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_line_widget.php');
include_once('widgets/rf_user_friendly_search_widget.php');
?>
```

Comment: Assuming this code is your entire functions.php file, line 72 is this one: `if ($_POST['page'] == $theme_name) {` (in `admin_script_loader()`). Add `global $theme_name;` to the beginning of said function, then change `if ($_POST['page'] == $theme_name) {` to `if ( isset($_POST['page']) && $_POST['page'] == $theme_name) {`.

Comment: I changed a code but now there are errors :
Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; ControlPanel has a deprecated constructor in D:\wordpress-4.9.5-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\page\backend\controlpanel.php on line 2

Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; CSS_Color has a deprecated constructor in D:\wordpress-4.9.5-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\page\csscolor.php on line 20